# How to stop greengrass core?

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass, aws-iot-core

I have installed greengrass core software and started it via:

```
sudo tar -xzvf greengrass-OS-architecture-1.11.0.tar.gz -C /
sudo tar -xzvf hash-setup.tar.gz -C /greengrass

cd /greengrass/certs/
sudo wget -O root.ca.pem https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem

cd /greengrass/ggc/core/
sudo ./greengrassd start
```

Verified that process is started via:

```
ps aux | grep PID-number
ps aux | grep -E 'greengrass.*daemon'
```

How to stop greengrass core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you need to run the following commands,

```
cd /greengrass-root/ggc/core/ 
sudo ./greengrassd stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Greengrass (both v1 and v2) runs as a systemd service, unless you have specified otherwise. To stop it you can run:

```
systemctl stop greengrass
```